# ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed in alpine-docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, python-imaging-library, alpine-linux

I am attempting to import and use the python pillow library like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import re
image = Image.open(urlopen("http://randomurl.com/randomimage.jpg"))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype("sans-serif.ttf", 16)
draw.text((0, 0),"This is the future liberals want",(255,255,255),font=font)
image.save('sample-out.jpg')
```

However, I get the following error:

```
/opt/bot/app # python cli.py 
Retrieving column Image ID on worksheet History
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli.py", line 38, in <module>
    font = ImageFont.truetype("sans-serif.ttf", 16)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 260, in truetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 135, in __init__
    if core.HAVE_RAQM:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 39, in __getattr__
    raise ImportError("The _imagingft C module is not installed")
ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed
```

I am aware that similar questions have been asked on StackOverflow before. However, all of the answers seem to deal with execution environments I am not targeting. I am running this in the `python:3.7-rc-alpine3.7` docker image and the existing answers do not work. Here are the pip and apk packages I have installed: http://dpaste.com/3EBW3A1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to install compiler (`g++`), TrueType font rendering library (`freetype-dev`) and accelerated baseline JPEG compression and decompression library (`jpeg-dev`) to compile `pillow` on Alpine platform.

The part of `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM python:3.7-rc-alpine3.7
RUN apk add --no-cache g++ freetype-dev jpeg-dev
RUN pip install pillow
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as you can see from my manifest, all three of these packages are currently installed. I have removed and re-installed pillow several times: http://dpaste.com/3EBW3A1

Comment: It is weird. I was able to get `sample-out.jpg` using your `cli.py` in a container built from above `Dockerfile`. BTW, I don't see compiler in your `apk info` output. Maybe it was deleted after?

Comment: Thanks for running that sample @Nickolay. I guess we'll never know what went wrong, but thanks to Docker I should be able to reset my dev environment to match yours anyway. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, don’t use these broken Docker images. It’s over and over again. Just use plain `alpine:3.7` image and install needed packages using `apk`. Pillow for Python 3 is provided by package `py3-pillow`, Python 3 by package `python3`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, that's useful to know. Can you go into more detail about how the images are broken?